# Database engine functionality

Tags: database, database-engine

I am working in a project at school (university) and we have to write a simple "DB Enngine" but I am not sure what this exactly means. I have read several definitions and what I understand is that we have to implement the functionality to create tables, drop tables, create indexes, read/select information from tables, write data to tables, update data, and so on. Am I right?

Respectfully,

Jorge Maldonado

Comment: Ask the person who gave you the project  for a clear problem statement ? What you mention is non-trivial depending on the level of detail you go into.

Answer (score 0):

A database engine is the underlying software component that a database management system (DBMS like mysql,oracle,sqlite etc..) uses to create, read, update and delete (CRUD) data from a database.

Example in **MySQL**:
when you pass a query **CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name column_type);**
the query is sent to database engine and it process the **CREATE TABLE** query and produce appropriate results.

Normally we use or pass query in  "database server" or "database management system". In both the cases database engine will process the query.

Technically the term "database engine" is frequently used interchangeably with "database server" or "database management system". A 'database instance' refers to the processes and memory structures of the running database engine.

**so whatever you mentioned in your question is right.**

Comment: I asked our professor just to make sure and yes, we will be implementing the functionality described above and I am already working on it. Now I have a second question. We are also asked to write a parser for syntax checking. Is there a formal method to achieve this? I know that (maybe a long time ago) state diagrams were used for syntax checking logic in compiler design. Is this still a modern/applicable approach?